# How to visibility toggle a group by 2 or more SSRS report items

Tags: reporting-services

I have a group defined that are "details" in the "Row Groups" configuration of my SSRS report.

Currently I have this "details" group set to visibility toggle with just one textbox item.

How would I configure SSRS such that the "details" group is toggled by 2 or more textbox items?

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2 - with toggle]

Comment: Can you post an image of the design, report XML and/or example records?

Comment: @aduguid Yes, thank you for your post.  Screenshot 1 shows the hierarchical row group structure set up.  Screenshot 2 shows the textbox that holds the drilldown (and the configuration dialog box that configures the drilldown [visibility toggle])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- toggle the visibility of the *Group1* group using the *Product_Foundational_Capability* textbox,
- toggle the visibility of the *Product_Foundational_Capability* group using the *Product_Segment* textbox,
- toggle the visibility of the *Product_Segment* group using the *Product_Top_Application* textbox
- toggle the visibility of the *Product_Top_Application* group using the *Product_System_Owner* textbox.

Each of these toggle buttons collapses/expands the groups/details below in the hierarchy, so all of them can also toggle visibility of the Details group.